# High Altitude Impulse Response

Tags: reverb, worldizing, impulse-response

Hey I was just wondering if anybody had a high altitude Impulse response or knew of any out there.

Comment: How high is high? I live Johannesburg, which is 5500ft high. I could try go get one if that is high enough, but is probably not though as it is acoustically similar to sea level (to my ears at least). 

Comment: What is an high altitude IR?

Comment: hmm.  near space?  tibet? mountains? 
lets go to everest and grab one.


Comment: I was just at 12,000' and there's usually no reverb at all at that height, period, unless you're in a cirque, canyon, or surrounded by cliffs, and even then, it's straight-up echo with no reverb. Crap, there I was, on the mountaintop with no starter pistol... ;-)

Comment: Well, high altitudes have less air pressure, so sound waves are less intense, ie. quieter.

Answer (score 2):

[2:46](http://vimeo.com/11907761)

Comment: :):):):):):):):)

Comment: Why would you want an impulse response of that? I can impulse response my dead/floating voice recording studio and it's the same difference. Totally dead ;)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what the questioner was expecting.  High altitude means that everything is quiet and there are zero reverberations.

Comment: I don't care what he meant, I just love that video.

Comment: It was a test to see if you were paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

"Yeah, I don't know what the questioner was expecting. High altitude means that everything is quiet and there are zero reverberations."

Wrong. If there are mountains around, you get amazing echoes. I was in Switzerland at the beginning of summer, and greatly regretted having no means to make an IR.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great idea, high altitudes definitely have a different sound, especially with snow on the ground.  Next time I'm skiing I'll try to grab something.  John.